# Setting jquery remove method as callback on animation complete doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a little game and in this game I need a disaster to happen every so often.
This disaster must shake my MainFrame element & remove all elements with the class .House, from a building array and from the DOM.

This code works to an extent, the problem is it doesn't remove the elements from the DOM, only from the array.
Can you help me get it working? 
My first time using this site, so I hope I didn't leave anything relevant out.

```
setInterval(function() {

    var iDisasterChance = getRandomNumber(1, 12);

    if (iDisasterChance === 1)
    {
        $(".MainFrame").effect("shake", {times: 8}, 4000);
        //$(".House").effect("explode", {pieces: 24}, 4000);
        $(".House").effect("explode", {pieces: 24}, 4000,  $(".House").remove); // TODO: bug - leaves elements in the dom
        //$(".House").remove();
        oCity.aBuildings.length = 0;
        console.log(iDisasterChance +' of 12');
        console.log('*** DISASTER ! AVOIDED ***');
        console.dir(oCity.aBuildings);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(iDisasterChance +' of 12');
        console.log('*** DISASTER AVOIDED ***');
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: As a suggestion, remember you can add **breakpoints** using your browser's console (or, prefereably, Firebug or similar) and check the code step by step (i.e. _line by line_), to see where it breaks... It is specially "useful" in linear codes such as this one. And remember to put it right at the beginning, in `var isDisasterChance = ...` in this case!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way. You need to `remove()` not `remove` and in a callback since you lose the context of jquery object inside the remove method.

```
$(".House").effect("explode", {pieces: 24}, 4000,  function(){
    $(this).remove(); //now this will get executed once your animation effect is complete and this represents the .House where the effect happened.
});
```

if you want to `remove` all .House then it must be.

```
$(".House").effect("explode", 
                              {pieces: 24}, 4000, 
                              $(".House").remove.bind($(".House"))); //bind will set the context to that of .House.
```

or

```
   $(".House").effect("explode", {pieces: 24}, 4000,function(){
          $(".House").remove();
   });
```

Reason being when you do:

```
$(".House").effect("explode", {pieces: 24}, 4000,  $(".House").remove));
```

OfCourse the `remove` method will be set in the callback with context most possibly of that of the `DOMelement` and not `jquery object` (as you see in regular call back as weel you get `this` as DOM element and it does not have a jquery version of remove method). so you can to use either `function.bind` to bind the context or `$.proxy` or just do it in the callback.

Comment: Not my downvote but as I can see he tries to remove all elements with the `House` class. Passing `$(".House").remove` does exactly that or am I missing something here? He just passes the function instead of creating an additional anonymous function.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder ofcourse that function gets executed without context, you set remove as reference to the call back it doesn't just get the context of `.House.`

Comment: Still not sure why this is necessary, thought `$('.House')` is executed right away and then the remove function of that object is passed as a callback. But seems like I have to dig into this a little bit :)

Comment: Check this fiddle and after that inspect DOM to see http://jsfiddle.net/TEnEa/ which element did not get removed.

Comment: Yes, I of course believe you, but It just doesn't make sense to me. Then you could also use: `$.prototype.remove.bind($(".House"))`?

Comment: @MarcelGwerder No it is not, sorry, it makes sense, if you think about it, callback of any jquery method gives `this` as dom element and not jquery object. and `this` doesnot have jquery version of remove method and same thing happens here it goes indside the jquery `remove` function as callback, which is same as a `jquery fn.something` needs `this` to be jquery object and not DOM element.

Comment: @PSL
The first solution you gave me also worked just fine? it removed all .house elements from the DOM. Am I missing something? also, cheers :)

Comment: @user2824478 what exactly you want to remove, all of them? Can you put this together in a fiddle?

Comment: @PSL Yes, I just want to remove all elements with the class .House, from the aBuilding array and the DOM itself (so they don't exist anymore) And the first solution you provided seems to do that trick, so should I still use the 2nd solution you posted, is it better in someway or?

Comment: @user2824478 If 1st solution works that is the best way, 3rd one as well. 2nd one is a hack (and you need to add a shim unless u use $.proxy for older browsers, since not all browsers support bind), you don't need to use that

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the exact context that this function will work in but I noticed two things about your code.

1. The post-effect code you have currently: `$('.House').remove` should be `$('.House').remove()` with the brackets otherwise you are just referencing the method and not actually calling it.
2. Your if statement only returns on one of its two cases, again i'm not sure what you are intending to do but I believe you may want to have a `return true;` in the `else` clause.

Hope these suggestions help.